# Webdriverio Junit Report xml file : shows duplicate test suite entries even when test suite is executed only once

Tags: xml, junit, package.json, webdriver-io, wdio

Node version - 14.21.3 NPM versiob - 6.14.18

I have webdriverio test framework in which the junit reporter is integrated. The test suite is executed only once. But the junit.xml file which is generated is showing the tests twice. For passed as well as failed test.

Anyone experienced such scenario. How to resolve this?

Following are the devdependencies in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.18.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.27.0",
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.19.7",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.31.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.27.0",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.26.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.26.0",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.17.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chromedriver": "^109.0.0",
    "totp-generator": "^0.0.13",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.8.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^3.1.1",
    "wdio-video-reporter": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

Following are the settings in wdio.conf.js file to run the tests

```
suites: {
    SANITY: [
      [
        "./test/specs/SmokeTest/001.testsuite1.spec.js",
        "./test/specs/SmokeTest/002.testsuite2.spec.js",
      ],
    ],
    
    
    REGRESSION: [
      [
        "./test/specs/RegressionTests/001.test3.spec.js",
        "./test/specs/RegressionTests/004.test4.spec.js",
      ],
    ]
```

This is how junit reporter is integrated in wdio.conf.js

```
reporters: ['dot',    
    ['junit', {
        outputDir: './reports',   
        outputFileFormat: function(options) { // optional
            return `results-file.xml`
        }
    }]
  ],
```

Each test is the spec file is defined like below

```
describe('a test suite', () => {
    it('a test case', function () {
      // do something
      // assert something
    });
});
```

There are no nested blocks.

Even then when the results-file.xml is generated it is showing the duplicate test suites.

Is there any solution for this issue?